# Django: Foreign key related list

Tags: python, django, templating

```
class Client(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False,null=False)

class Expense(models.Model):

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False,null=False)
    amount= models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2)
    #currency = models.CharField(max_length = 5)
    from_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    to_date  = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    Description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I have two models above where `Expense` should be the object of  `Client` . 
how to write templating part:

1.To get list of clients .

2.If we click on the client , should get list of expenses list related to the client.....

Comment: This is a bit broad. Since it's exactly the same as the Question/Answer setup in the tutorial, where are you having trouble that is not covered there?

Comment: Absolutely your question is way too broad @Mahesh, can you please narrow it down. E.g. where are you at in writing the template and where have you failed. What have you tried to do which has failed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand your problem, but i'm going to answer what i understand.

1. To get list of clients:
   `Client.objects.all()`
2. List of expenses related to the client

`Client.expense_set.all()`